# HTML (for angular) validation - different behavior with name and id attributes

Tags: html, angular, intellij-idea, syntax-error, lint

I'm trying to get as clean as possible when writing code. My IDE is IntelliJ (ultimate), I activated validation before commit/push. There is a strange behavior that I got there where I cannot pass the validation when providing a concatenation for an input name attribute, while no issue is raised for the id attribute:

```
        <div *ngFor="let item of commandBuilder.items; let y = index">
            <input clrInput style="..."
                   type="text"
                   pattern="0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+"
                   [(ngModel)]="item.hexaValue"
                   id="{{item.name + 'hexInput'}}"
                   name="{{item.name + 'hexInput'}}" />
        </div>
```

3 errors are raised on the line of name:

- char 31 (just before item.name): *Identifier or string literal or numeric literal expected*
- char 36: *: or , expected*
- char 37: *: expected*

To give a little bit more context, here is the relevant parts of the ts file:

```
   commandBuilder = { } as CommandBuilder;
```

And the relevant parts of the interfaces:

```
export interface CommandBuilder {
  items: CommandDetailItem[];
}

export interface CommandDetailItem {
  name: string;
}
```

Any idea how I can pass the validation or an explanation on why it's doing that for name attribute and not id attribute?

Comment: Can you provide the associated/relevant code behind this html? I can't tell if the issue is with Angular's interpolation or with the attribute.

Comment: I added some context, thanks for looking at it.

Answer (score 0):

There is an ongoing bug on JetBrains side. I guess this is the cause: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-48808/Binding-in-name-attribute-is-marked-as-incorrect